# Xcode: Unsupported OS version, iphone os version 14.7 & Xcode 12.5.1

Tags: flutter, operating-system, version, xcode13

i am trying to build my flutter app on my iphone 11 with iOS version of 14.7 and my xcode is 12.5, I have seen that there is Xcode 13 but i don't have that update on the appstore, my mac version is Big Surr 11.5.2

what do i do?

Comment: if the Xcode version is your problem. Use this link and download Xcode 13 [Xcode 13](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/).

Answer (score 0):

If your Mac is too old to load the latest version of macOS, Sonoma 14.2.1, you won't be able to load the latest version of Xcode, version 15, and because of that, you won't be able to build and load for iOS v14.

I spent a few days last week trying out various workarounds because I have an old MacBook Air (2013) which can only run up to Big Sur.
I eventually bought a factory-refurbished MacBook 16" M1 Pro (2022), which was not my first choice, but I have it now and it works great.

Note: I didn't figure this out until I uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode from the App Store when it pointed out that my OS was too old for the latest version Xcode.

Some threads are talking about how to fake out Xcode with new device files but Apple support pointed out that was completely unsupported. Also, I couldn't get it to work. YMMV

Comment: You do not need macOS 14.2 to run Xcode 15. I'm running Xcode 15.1 just fine on an older Mac with macOS 13.6 without any hacks. Also, iOS 14 is more than 3 years old. You don't need the latest of anything to support iOS 14. Maybe you meant iOS 17.